# How to automatically add something to value $address?

Tags: php, forms

I have this:

```
echo '<input type="text" id="address" name="address" value="'.$address.'" />';
```

When you enter your adress (my+adress) in search form and hit button "Search" I want to search automatically add cityname and country in link, to link look like .../index.php?address=my+adress+citiname+county.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So just use a `method="get"` in the post field and it will dump the fields to the URL?

```
<form action="" method="get">
    <input  type="text" name="myAddress">
    <input type="text" name="city">
    <input type="text" name="county">
    <input type="submit" value="Go Search">
</form>
```

If you don't want to add in the fields, you will need to parse the `myAddress` field and use a `meta redirect` to populate the data you parsed from their address.

Comment: Tnx! It works! **echo '<input type="hidden" id="address" name="cityname county" value="'.$address.'">';** Now link look like ...index.php?address=my+adress&cityname+county, but script don't do the job, to script do the job link  need to be like this: ...index.php?address=my+adress+cityname+county, that is because I have 2 input, and  need that in one... something to add near value="'.$address.'" or?

Answer (score 0):

It would be much more straightforward to either:

- add cityname and country in index.php, if those are known in _SESSION

or:

- add a (possibly hidden) field in the form with cityname and address, even if you will receive two different values from your form and require merging them

To do **exactly** what you want, you need to modify the query just before it is submitted; it is easiest to do this, e.g., using jQuery.

Comment: Tnx! It works with second one! **echo '<input type="hidden" id="address" name="cityname county" value="'.$address.'">';** Now link look like ...index.php?address=my+adress&cityname+county, but script don't do the job, to script do the job link  need to be like this: ...index.php?address=my+adress+cityname+county, that is because I have 2 input, and  need that in one... something to add near value="'.$address.'" or? Your first option is hard for me but tnx!